# Dotnet Core 2.2 - Azure AD Auth Work but Roles Base Returns Access Denied

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to get roles working in .Net Core 2.2 and none of the other solutions have worked.

In the `Startup.cs`, Microsoft generates this code in a new .Net 2.2 which doesn't work for some reason but getting this block to work isn't the topic though it would be nice to know why it doesn't. Says "No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found." But it is what Microsoft generated.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

In my real `Startup.cs` I've had to use what's below

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
            .AddCookie();
```

So the above is the only way I've gotten Azure AD to work with the `[Authorize]` attribute. The issue is that when I try to authorize with roles. I've tried many of the suggestions but haven't had any success. Anytime I have an `[Authorize(Roles="")]` I get redirected to the `AccessDenied()` method in the `AccountController` that Microsoft generated for Azure AD, basically Access Denied. I'm using roles that I've made in AD, also made a group in Azure AD, also using a role called "Domain Users" which is basically given to every employee in the company and is the most basic authorization that every employee has. If "Domain Users" gets "access denied" then I have no idea what I'm not understanding here.

I've followed Microsoft docs for roles but there's nothing there that says I need to add more to the `services.AddAuthentication()` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's working for me, .Net Core 2.2 Web App using Roles.

Edited application Manifest to include roles, E.g.

```
"appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User"
            ],
            "description": "Admins have the power.",
            "displayName": "Admin",
            "id": "282fc418-cf3a-4a3a-89f8-6500c64695ff",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "Admin"
        },
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User"
            ],
            "description": "Writers have the ability to edit app data.",
            "displayName": "Writer",
            "id": "3aa1a322-2918-4005-8cc3-51cba010ccc0",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "Writer"
        },
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User"
            ],
            "description": "Readers have the ability to read app data.",
            "displayName": "Reader",
            "id": "239f93af-4cc0-4d0e-ad04-bda1f8ac2a91",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "Reader"
        }
    ]
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddCookie();

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Add extensions to workaround the issue you mentioned, in your "top block" of code.

AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs

```
public static class AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
        => builder.AddAzureAd(_ => { });

    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
        builder.AddOpenIdConnect();
        return builder;
    }

    private class ConfigureAzureOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
    {
        private readonly AzureAdOptions _azureOptions;

        public ConfigureAzureOptions(IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureOptions)
        {
            _azureOptions = azureOptions.Value;
        }

        public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        {
            options.ResponseType = "token id_token";
            options.Resource = _azureOptions.TargetApiAppId;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
            options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
            options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
            options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        }

        public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        {
            Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
        }
    }
}
```

AzureADOptions.cs

```
public class AzureAdOptions
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
    public string Instance { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public string CallbackPath { get; set; }

    //manually added
    public string TargetApiAppId { get; set; }
}
```

Assign role to the user in Enterprise applications blade:

[image]

Decorate your controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Writer")]
```

AccountController.cs

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignIn()
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl },
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignOut()
    {
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
        return SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignedOut()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Redirect to home page if the user is authenticated.
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }

        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AccessDenied()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I found out also. Have to use application roles defined in the app manifest. What's cool though is that a role can be created in our regular on premise AD which will show up in Azure AD. That role can be assigned to the application with one of the roles created in the app manifest. Then every time you add a user to the on premise AD, it will automatically get access once it syncs up to Azure AD.

Comment: Cool indeed! I'm doing that in another Web App, combine it with Policy based auth and it becomes quite powerful. E.g.

`services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Analyst", policy => policy.RequireRole("DataAnalyst"));
                options.AddPolicy("Reader", policy =>
                    policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                        context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "DataAnalyst") || context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "DataReader")));
            });`

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the application manifest in AzureAD to receive the AD roles.

Change the "groupMembershipClaims" value in the manifest to "All".

Note that if you have a large number of groups you can end up making the response too big, so all may want trimmed down to just those groups you actually want to flow.

Comment: I changed it to "all" but I'm not getting anything different back. No roles or groups. How would you trim down to the values you want also? I couldn't specify the types of roles that I wanted, said invalid values. Still I wasn't getting any of them.

Comment: At this point I can only point to the AzureAD docs, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims

Comment: Is this for .Net Core?

Comment: Yea unfortunately this is for .Net, we are looking for the solution to .Net Core which is different.

Comment: Flowing the groups should still happen with the flags, that is not .net version specific. Add a breakpoint and see if the user contains role claims. If it doesn’t it’s probably an AAD configuration problem.

Comment: I did add a breakpoint and looked pretty hard for anything that wasn't there before. Didn't see anything about roles as there should have been a whole lot. If this was working, should roles be showing up in claims?

Comment: Yes, roles are basically claims of the role type claim.

Comment: Maybe it took a moment to filter out but yes now I'm seeing a ton of group entries! This could be a winner! Upon inspecting the groups, I don't see anything about the name of that group. I suppose I could try authenticate with roles again and see if it works now but I don't see the names of the groups so I don't know. Do you know if roles and groups are the same thing?

Comment: Once I can get someone to grant the group permission I'm requesting, I'll see if my above statement changes. Do you know if I start pulling groups correctly that the `[Authorize(Roles="role")]` attribute will work?

Comment: Just remember the groups won't be in the token if there are too many of them. For example 200 is the max for a JWT.

Answer (score 1):

Please first confirm that you get the groups in token , After changing the "groupMembershipClaims" value in the manifest to "All" , you can put below code in controller :

```
 var claims = User.Claims;
```

After user is authenticated in application , you should get the `groups` claims :

[image]

Then you can use an attribute with a named policy then you define the policy in startup to require group claim and set allowed Group ID :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        "CanAccessGroup",
        policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", "0c71eab2-6618-4c53-bcce-806xxxxxx"));
});
```

In controller :

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CanAccessGroup")]
public IActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

If the group id is not in the user group claims, access will denied .

> > Says "No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found." But it is what Microsoft generated.

I haven't meet this error if using the default `Work or School Accounts` template in VS2017 , the installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` package version will be `v2.2.0` , and the generated codes are :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Comment: I guess that's the best way I've seen so far. I was hoping to get the `[Authorize(Roles=""]` attribute working, can we not do that with groups?

When I use the `services.AddAuthentication` code that they generated in the templates, that's what I get.

Comment: This is working, but the problem is that I'm getting 100s of groups back. Only option to trim it down is to use the value "Security Groups" which leaves me at 100s still. I guess there's no other way to trim this down. But the request/response is too large and it shows `Bad Request`.

Comment: @DanielJackson , then you should not use groups , use roles ,  you can define the roles in your app in the app manifest,  then assign users to them. Once you do those two things, there will be claim called "roles" in the JWT you get, which contains the user's role .

Comment: Yup you're right, it took a moment for the affect to filter out but I'm now getting the application role in code and `[Authorize(Roles="role")]` is working! Thank you for the help.